# Specifying RSA OAEP label via OpenSSL command line

Tags: openssl

Is there a way to pass the OAEP label to OpenSSL command-line tools?

For a specific example, consider this command for RSA OAEP encryption that does not specify the label:

`openssl rsautl -encrypt -oaep -inkey path_to_key.pem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [source](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0h/apps/rsautl.c) it does not appear that such an option exists for `rsautl`. After some digging however, I discovered that [`pkeyutl`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0h/apps/pkeyutl.c) supports the [`rsa_oaep_label`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0h/crypto/rsa/rsa_pmeth.c#L587) option as a hex string:

```
openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -inkey path_to_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep -pkeyopt rsa_oaep_label:[hex string]
```